# pyspark - date column with null values not filling with old date

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

In the following `Hiring_date` is of `DateType`. df2 fills the null dates as '1900-01-01'. But the date format of actual data is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Hence I want the null values to be filled as `01/01/1900`. So, I tried the code shown in second block below; but the `Hiring_date` column still showed null values as NULL.

**Question**: What I may be missing and how can we fix it? I guess more important part of the question would be: Why Code 2 is ignoring the `01/01/1900` allotter

**Code 1**: Fills the null date values as '1900-01-01'. But I need the `01/01/1900` format

```
df1 = df..withColumn("Hiring_date", df.Hiring_date.cast(DateType()))
df2 = df1.fillna( {'Hiring_date': '1900-01-01'} )
```

**Code 2**: Fills the null date values as NULL. But I need it to display `01/01/1900`

```
df1 = df..withColumn("Hiring_date", df.Hiring_date.cast(DateType()))
df2 = df1.fillna( {'Hiring_date': '01/01/1900'} )
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only valid string format for inputting DateType is `yyyy-MM-dd` which explains why your first code is working.

You seem to be wanting a string representation of the date, which you can achieve with:

`df.withColumn('Hiring_date', date_format(col('Hiring_date'), 'MM/dd/yyyy'))`

Comment: With your suggestion, will `df2 = df1.fillna( {'Hiring_date': '01/01/1900'} )` also work?

Comment: If you want to do that you need to treat it as as string column, not a date column

Comment: I will agree with Chris - _date_ type columns cannot display 01/01/1900, as this does not conform with the only available _date_ format, i.e. yyyy-MM-dd. If you need other format than yyyy-MM-dd, you will need another column with this format, but it will have to be _string_ type, because _date_ type columns can only have yyyy-MM-dd format.